# Cronjob to be scheduled

Tags: shell, unix, cron, scheduling

I have to schedule a job in Unix which runs every other monday, I have set a cronjob using crontab

```
00 00 * * 1/2 jobname.sh
```

Will it work ?

Comment: Why don't you try it?  You can set it to run every hour on Thursday (today) and see if it runs every hour today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all users having problems with cron expressions:

there are multiple tools to generate or validate your cron expressions.

One of them is http://cronmaker.com/, which is online and free.